# How to calculate the volume given by $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 = xyz$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I am working on the following exercise:

> Calculate the volume of the body bounded by the following surface:
>
> $$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 = xyz$$

I would solve this with a triple integral, but I do not see how I can derive the boundaries from $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 = xyz$. I guess one way to do this would be to use spherical coordinates, i.e we substitute

$$x = r \cdot \sin(\theta) \cos(\varphi), y = r \cdot \sin(\theta) \sin(\varphi), z = \cos(\theta) $$

, but I can't take it further from there. Could you help me?

Comment: I updated my answer. Check it and see if it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mea maxima culpa. The previous version of this post calculated the *area* incorrectly. I've given a hopefully correct calculation of the volume below.

We have (as you can check)
$$
r^4 = r^3 \sin^2 \theta \cos  \theta  \sin \phi \cos\phi
$$
So
$$
r =  \sin^2 \theta\cos\theta \sin\phi \cos\phi \equiv f(\theta , \phi)
$$
at the boundary of the volume. Following the advice of Empy2, we compute the volume in the first octant:
\begin{align}
V_1 &= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{f(\theta, \phi)} r^2 \sin \theta \ dr \, d\theta \, d\phi 
\\&= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{(f(\theta, \phi))^3}{3} \sin \theta \ d\theta \, d\phi 
\\&= \frac{1}{3}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^7\theta \cos^3 \theta \ d\theta \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^3 \phi \cos^3 \phi \ d\phi
\\&= \frac{1}{12}\int_0^1 u^3(1 - u) \ du \int_0^{1} v(1 - v) \ dv
\\&= \frac{1}{12} \left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5} \right)\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} \right)
\\&= \frac{1}{12} \cdot \frac{1}{20} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{1440}
\end{align}
We notice that the defining equation of the surface has no solutions with an odd number of the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ negative (the LHS is always positive, so the RHS cannot be negative). It's also interesting to note that if any one of the coordinates of a solution $(x,y,z)$ to the equation is $0$, then the rest must also be $0$ to have equality. Finally, observe that if any two of the coordinates of a solution $(x,y,z)$ are multiplied by $-1$, then the resulting point is also a solution. This shows that the surface consists of $4$ identical lobes intersecting only at the origin, with each lobe contained entirely in an octant with an even number of positive coordinates. Therefore, the total volume is
$$
V = 4 V_1 = \frac{1}{360}
$$

Comment: $r^2 \sin \theta \, d\theta d\phi$ is not the area element for the given surface.

Comment: What is the correct area element?

Comment: If the surface is parametrized as $\boldsymbol r(u, v)$, then
$$dS = \left| \frac {\partial \boldsymbol r} {\partial u} \times
 \frac {\partial \boldsymbol r} {\partial v} \right| du dv.$$
The surface integral will not be elementary. The volume integral over the solid bounded by the surface is elementary.

Comment: Yes. The surface is parametrized by $\vec{r}(\theta, \phi) = (r(\theta , \phi)\sin \theta \cos \phi , r(\theta , \phi) \sin \theta \sin \phi, r(\theta , \phi)\cos \theta)$ where $r(\theta , \phi) = \sqrt{\sin^2 \theta\cos \theta\sin\phi\cos\phi}$. When we compute the volume element according to your formula for the first octant, we find $dS = (r(\theta, \phi))^2 \sin \theta \ d\theta \, d\phi$, as claimed. This is a lengthy calculation and the result is, I think, considered well-known, so I omitted it. Note that this exact formula would hold mutatis mutandis if $r(\theta, \phi)$ were different

Comment: To further clarify, $dS = (r(\theta, \phi))^2 \sin\theta \ d\theta \, d\phi$ is a general fact about surfaces where $r$ is parametrized by $\theta$ and $\phi$ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I misremembered having once carried out this calculation and finding this result, but it only holds for constant $r$. The integral will not be elementary.

Comment: Sorry again. I somehow completely missed that the OP was asking for volume and not area, which is a much simpler calculation. For the record, I computed the area element and it was not pleasant. I'd appreciate if the OP would unaccept my answer so that I can delete it. Failing that, I'll update the answer with the area calculation.

Comment: The author of the question does not get notified when comments are added to an answer (or even when an answer gets edited). If you wish, you can add a comment to the question itself saying that your answer has been updated and you can modify your answer to show the volume computation.

Comment: This is still wrong. The first line should be $r^4 = r^3\sin^2\theta\cos\theta \sin\phi\cos\phi$. That means your $f$ needs no square roots.

Comment: You're right. I was going off the typo in the OP which had $z = \cos\theta$. I'll fix it again.

Answer (score 3):

Get $r$ in terms of $\theta$ and $\phi$, then do a triple integral with dr on the inside.  I would do just the first octant, then multiply by whatever to get the full volume.